# Is it safe to test and erase a drive after removing it from a RAID1 array with mdadm?

Tags: raid, mdadm, raid1

I have a faulty drive in my RAID1 array (SMART errors, data corruption). I have marked it as failed and removed it from the array with `mdadm`:

```
# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1

# mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdb1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sdb1

# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid5] [raid4] [raid6] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      24418688 blocks [2/1] [U_]

unused devices: <none>
```

At this point, the failed drive (sdb) should no longer be mounted or used by the system in any way, correct?

Is it now safe to do write tests and erase it with `dd` or `badblock` without removing it from the server?